# Split a column in lines after every 5 entries - awk

Tags: awk, rows

I have a file that looks like the following

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
12
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
4
```

What I want to do is convert this column in multiple rows. Each new line/row should start after 5 entries, so that the output will like like this

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 12 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 3
4
```

I tried to achieve that by using

```
awk '{printf "%s" (NR%5==0?"RS:FS),$1}' file
```

but I get the following error

```
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "RS:FS),$1} ...
```

Any idea on how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Theres a double quote before RS.

Comment: @123 Thanks for your comment! This was it!!! HOwever since I am not quite familiar with `awk`, what was the problem there? To be quite frank, I am not certain about the `printf "%s" (NR%5==0?"RS:FS),$1` command either;I just found it on SE. Could you post an answer, explaining the command sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this awk one liner can help.

```
awk '{if (NR%5==0){a=a $0" ";print a; a=""} else a=a $0" "}END{print}' file
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 12 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 3
4
```

Longer awk:

```
{
    if (NR%5==0)
    {
       a=a $0" ";
       print a;
       a="";
    }
    else
    {
       a=a $0" ";
    }
 }
 END
 {
    print
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach, still using awk:

```
$ awk '{if (NR%5) {ORS=""} else {ORS="\n"}{print " "$0}}' input.txt
 1 1 1 1 1
 1 12 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 3
 4
```

Using `perl`:

```
$ perl -p -e 's/\n/ / if $.%5' input.txt
1 1 1 1 1
1 12 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate...

```
$ pr -5ats' ' <file

1 1 1 1 1
1 12 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 3
4
```